# ng-repeat through multiple array locations

Tags: angularjs, html

I have data coming in and am trying to display the rows it fills with ng-repeat. Here is how the data looks coming in:

[image]

SO I am trying to display it on the view:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts">
     <tr>
          <td><div data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="true" data-strat-model="contract" data-field="contracts[0].ndc_id"></div></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Typing `{{contract.ndc_id}}` or `{{contracts.ndc_id}}` returns nothing.
 However, `{{contracts[0].ndc_id}}` returns the expected data.

But There will be multiple contracts in the array and this will only account for the 1st one it looks like.

Why isn't ng-repeat iterating using (contract in contracts)? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in contracts[0]"> 
      {{contracts[0][key]}} |  {{value}}
       <div ng-if="$index === 1"> This is the second value {{value}}</div>
       <div ng-if="$index === 2"> This is the thrid value {{value}}</div>
       <div ng-if="$last"> This is the last value {{value}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is great and returns all of the data I need. But how do I choose where the 2nd value for example goes? How do I set value to one of the specific properties I want?

Comment: define *set* , do you want to set scope variables values inside the view?

Comment: Yes, I want to set different different <divs> to certain values coming through. For example 'ndc_id' or 'quote_price' in the view.

Answer (score 1):

According to your data, it looks like an object, you cannot do ng-repeat over your object,

However you can do this in order to read the properties and values,

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in contracts"> {{key}} |  {{value}}</div>
```

Comment: You can iterate over the properties of an object using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: what i meant was his data